# How to add a border to an image rather than the image view?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I am building a "photo gallery" for my app. When a user taps on an image I want a blue border to appear (to show that it is selected). Since I am using the content mode `.scaleAspectFit`, the image almost never takes up the full image view resulting in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCKya.png). I want the border to be just around the image itself like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3gV5.png) (the red border). How would I accomplish this?

My code...

```
imageView.image = images[index]
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 5
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the aspect ratio of the imageView equal to the aspect of the image [ by creating all images to be same aspect ratio ] and give the imageView screen width minus border width

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve that effect with features of a UIImageView. You will need to customize something and there are a lot of approaches that could achieve the effect you want.

One easy solution is to do that scaling yourself. Aspect fit is extremely easy to compute. [Here is an example I found](https://gist.github.com/jkosoy/c835fea2c03e76720c77).

Once you have computed the scaled image size, set the frame of the UIViewView to that size. Now your image will take up 100% of the UIImageView and your border will align properly!